# Solving simultaneous equations with imaginary numbers

Tags: number-systems

Consider the following simultaneous equation:

$$\begin{cases} 5z-(3+i)w=7-i\\ (2-i)z+2iw = -1+i \end{cases} $$

What is the simplest way to manipulate one of the equations so that a variable can be eliminated and the equation solved?

Comment: w = -16i-10
z= -3i + 14? Are these correct anyone tried them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it the same way you do it over the reals. For example, you could solve the first equation for $z$, $z=(7-i+(3+i)w)/5$, substitute that into the 2nd equation, solve for $w$, then get $z$. Or, multiply the first equation by $2-i$, the second by 5, and subtract to eliminate $z$.

Comment: I vote for multiplication by $2-i$ and $5$.

Comment: In this example, it looks like multiplying the second equation by $2+i$ might be easier.

Comment: Mike, yes, for this example, that looks like a very good idea.